# send parameter url

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am sending the values to a controller doing this

```
echo $html->link('Do this? ',"/item/view/{$form->value('table.id')}");
```

on the controller end cake just pickups the id like this

```
function view($id = null){
....
}
```

Now in addition to table.id, I want to send another value called table2.source ...how would I do that so the controller also gets it

`function view($id = null, $source=null) ...`something along those lines but not sure how will they get to the controller in first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just change the link url to something like this:

```
echo $html->link('Do this? ',
    "/item/view/{$form->value('table.id')}/{$form->value('table2.source')}");
```

(After changing the view function to accept the second parameter...)